# How to configure RSpec to find specs in lib folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, load-path

I am creating a little API with Rails 5.0 following this tutorial http://apionrails.icalialabs.com/book/frontmatter

I am trying to run a test located in `app/config/lib` but RSpec won't find the test.

I have tried adding `config.autoload_paths << Rails.root.join('lib')` or
`config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)` to `app/config/application.rb`.

This is my code:

```
$ /app/config/application.rb

#required files go here, deleted for clarity.

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module MarketPlaceApi
  class Application < Rails::Application

    # don't generate RSpec tests for views and helpers
    config.generators do |g|
      g.test_framework :rspec, fixture: true
      g.fixture_replacement :factory_girl, dir: 'spec/factories'
      g.view_specs false
      g.helper_specs false
      g.stylesheets = false
      g.javascripts = false
      g.helper = false
    end

  config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib)
  end
end
```

Test

```
$ app/config/lib/spec/test_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe ApiConstraints do
  #test goes here
end
```

How can I add the `lib` folder so RSpec runs the tests located in it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RSpec doesn't look for tests in `autoload_paths`. If you run `rspec` or `rake spec` without arguments, RSpec looks in the `spec` directory by default. If you want to run specs in a different directory, give that directory to `rspec` as an argument:

```
rspec app/config/lib/spec
```

However, it's the universal convention to keep your specs in the `spec` directory, separate from your code in `app` and `lib`, so I'd move your specs to `spec/lib`. RSpec will then find them without any extra effort.

Comment: load_path doesn't contain '.', it confusing me when require library in spec path not my test path